# Provide public key for google service account instead of having Google generate the key

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

With Google service accounts, Google generates the public/private key pair associated with the service account and passes that along to the end user who wants to make API calls.  And its up to the end user to keep the keys safe.  Is it possible to generate a service account and an associated client, but provide a certificate that Google can use to validate the service account client making the request?  The problem I'm trying to solve is not to exchange any private keys.

Also is it possible to scope the users a service account has access to?  For example if I wanted to create a service account that only has impersonation api access rights on a sub set of users on the Google domain.  From what I've read if you create a service account with domain wide delegation, the service account has impersonation api rights for ALL users on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot associate service account and provide a certificate to validate the client request. As stated [`here`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#overview) a service account's credentials is unique and at least one public or private key pair. To generate service account credentials, go to Google Developers Console. In the Create service account window, type a name for the service account and select `Furnish a new private key`. Your private/public key pair is generated and download to your machine. It serves as the only copy of this key. You are responsible for storing it securely. For more details about service account credentials in the Developers Console, see [`Service account`](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862#service-accounts) in the Developers Console help file.